# Datepicker not supporting timepicker

Tags: plugins, custom-field, forms, front-end, date-time

The `datepicker` is working perfect but `datetimepicker` is not working at front side in wordpress-4.6.1.

**Edit**

I have got this in static html using `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` but i don't want to use this picker in wordpress. I want to achive this only using wordpress datepicker. Is it possible?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" value="" />
<input type="text" name="datetime" id="datetime" value="" />
```

**wp_enqueue_scripts**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_datepicker');
function custom_datepicker() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');    
}
```

**JS**

```
add_action('wp_head','custom_header_script');
function custom_header_script() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#date1').datepicker();
            $('#datetime').datepicker({
               timeFormat:'hh:mm'
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: so what is the question? what debuging effort have you tried?

Comment: I want to display time in `datetime ` textbox but it will show date only.

Comment: ok, so still what is the question, and how is it specific to wordpress?

Comment: Because i want to do it in my functions.php file using js files of wordpress which are in wp-includes folder .

Comment: Please review my edit.

Comment: better, but that library that you want to use is just a jquery libray, I am not aware that there is a wordpress specific one. So best thing is likely to consult jquery documentation, or ask on stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress supports only datepicker. If you want to add timepicker in datepicker you have to use `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon` as extension in your theme or plug-in.

**Add css and js as below**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_datepicker');
function custom_datepicker() {
    //wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    //wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');          
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-timepicker-addon',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js',array());
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-timepicker-addon',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css',array());
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/jquery-ui.css',array());  
}
```

You can download all css and js files from this link http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

**Call timepicker as below**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#datetime').datetimepicker({
          timeFormat: "hh:mm",
          dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working but i want know it is default in wordpress

Comment: You can use now the `datetime-local` HTML element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local